# Sound name from UNNotificationSound

Tags: ios, swift, audio, push-notification, swift3

I am working with push notifications in CloudKit. Here is what I used before Swift 3:

```
notification.soundName = UILocalNotificationDefaultSoundName
```

(notification is a `CKNotificationInfo`)

However, this gives me a warning:

> 'UILocalNotificationDefaultSoundName' was deprecated in iOS 10.0: Use UserNotifications Framework's +[UNNotificationSound defaultSound]

So I added the UserNotification framework to my Xcode project, and I imported it to my ViewController. I then tried this:

```
notification.soundName = UNNotificationSound.default()
```

However, this gives me an error:

> Cannot assign value of type 'UNNotificationSound' to type 'String?'

So the default sound is a `UNNotificationSound`, but I need the sound name. How can I get the sound name from the sound? Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the new `UserNotifications` framework:

```
import UserNotifications

let content = UNMutableNotificationContent()
content.sound = UNNotificationSound.default()

let request = UNNotificationRequest(identifier: "id", content: content, trigger: nil)
```

Comment: This isn't exactly what I was looking for... I do not believe I need a `UNNotificationRequest`. Also, content.sound is get-only unfortunately.

Comment: .sound is get-only for UNNotificationContent, but if you use UNMutableNotificationContent you can set it to the sound you want to use.

Answer (score 2):

Sadly I think the answer here is that even though we've gotten a lot of great stuff with the new UserNotifications framework, CloudKit and `CKNotificationInfo` specifically didn't get updated for it.

Best bet at the moment, is to use what `UILocalNotificationDefaultSoundName` has normally returned, and use `"default"`.